# How do I flag an extension which no longer works?

Tags: extension

just to save anyone else some time.. I tried one  and couldn't get it to work.  I contacted the author and he confirmed it doesn't work and wont be updated.

so to save the next person going down the same route.. can I flag it?

Answer (score 1):

Is this an extension that is published in the CiviCRM extension directory? At the moment I do not think you can flag an extension as not working, but it would be nice if the author removed it from the extension directory if he/she agrees it no longer works.

If it is a case of it does not work with version 4.7 but it does work with version 4.6 that will show on the extension page where the supported versions are mentioned. But IMO that is not a 'it does not work', more a 'it does not work with my version'.

I think you should add a little more information about your statement?

Comment: thanks Erik.. my question was a general one but it was triggered by one specific instance. To answer your question yes it is in the directory and no its nothing to do with version capability.  For perfectly understandable reasons, it no long works.. I just wanted to save people time in trying it out

Comment: And that makes total sense to me Robinnz, and it is great that you want to share this!